# Two URI objects are equal but their toString() are not

Tags: java, file, path, java-8, uri

I do not understand why two files' `URI`s are equal but their `String` representation are not equal. Is it a bug?

```
assertEquals(new File(".").toURI(), Paths.get(".").toUri()); // pass
assertEquals(new File(".").toURI().toString(), Paths.get(".").toUri().toString()); // fail

// org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
// Expected :file:/path/to/the/directory/./
// Actual   :file:///path/to/the/directory/./
```

### UPDATE 1

I understand that, technically, you can completely have the implementation, where two objects are equal based on `equals` method, but have different `toString()` result.

However, I am just curious, in the case of class `URI`, is it a good implementation: two `URI`s are equal but with different string representation.

In my case, it is different because there are having different `getAuthority()` result. But then, why they are equal? It is confusing. If I did not print out the result and check the source code of it, I will not be aware of this.

### UPDATE 2

According to @VGR 's comment below, I did another test as following:

```
    System.out.println(new File(".").toURI()); // file:/path/to/the/directory/./
    System.out.println(Paths.get(".").toUri()); // file:///path/to/the/directory/./
    System.out.println(new File(".").toURI().getAuthority()); // null
    System.out.println(Paths.get(".").toUri().getAuthority()); // null
```

As you can see, if we get `authority` from both of these two `URI`s, it is `null` in both cases.

However, they do not have same `toString()` output.

Comment: When I made those URIs, their string forms looked the same as yours, but both of them returned null from their respective `getAuthority()` methods, both in Java 8 and Java 9.  So, they are indeed equal.

Comment: @VGR added your comment as UPDATE 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `URI#toString()` method is well documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#toString()):

> Returns the content of this URI as a string.
>   If this URI was created by invoking one of the constructors in this class then a string equivalent to the original input string, or to the string computed from the originally-given components, as appropriate, is returned. Otherwise this URI was created by normalization, resolution, or relativization, and so a string is constructed from this URI's components according to the rules specified in RFC 2396, section 5.2, step 7.

meaning, the result of `toString()` method depends on the way we init the URI object (in total [5 constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html).)

In this case, you're trying to init 2 URI objects in 2 different ways, so that the results of `toString()` are different. Can try [`normalize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#normalize()) method.

Comment: I understand.  But it should not be like this right?  It’s confusing

Answer (score 0):

There is not such contract as if two objects are equals string representation need to be same. Java `equals` implementation is independent from `toString` method. e.g instances of following class are all equals but they do not have same toString representation.

```
public class Foo {

    private String value;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

In your particular case both `URI` instance are equals because they point to the same path but string representation is different because one of them contains redundant information. Try using [normalize](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#normalize()) method before toString

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the equals method is validating that they point to the same **resource** only. However, the **Uniform Resource Identifier string of characters** is different because they access to the same resource in two different ways.

It's like going to a store and buying a $1 soda with $1 bill, or 4 quarters coins: you would gain access to the same soda using different ways to acquire it. The guy at the cash register says paying either way would be equally good, although he knows there's a clear difference between a bill and a bunch of coins.